# Dynamic attribute name

Tags: angularjs

I defined this constant:

```
constant('countries', [{
            NAME_IT: "Francia",
            NAME_US: "France"
        },
        {
            NAME_IT: "Italy",
            NAME_US: "Italia"
        }
    ]);
```

I want to display the name of the country following a language (IT or US) that I define in my controller `language`:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cc in ctrl.countries">
        <!-- cc.NAME_US or cc.NAME_IT -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can't find a way to display the dynamic attribute `NAME_US` or `NAME_IT`. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code of your controller as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created a method in my controller that returns the value of the name like this:

```
getCountryName(country) {
        return country["NAME_" + this.profile.language];
    }
```

This way I no longer have a problem of a dynamic attibute name, I just call my method:

```
<li ng-repeat="cc in countriesList">
      {{ctrl.getCountryName()}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `constant` into `controller` and then and assign it to some `$scope` property of controller and then bind that scope property to you HTML.

For example : In controller:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "countries", function ($scope, countries) {
    $scope.countriesList = countries;
   //other code
}]);
```

further in HTML, like :

```
<li ng-repeat="cc in countriesList">
      {{cc.NAME_IT}} -{{cc.NAME_US}}
</li>
```

See this [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fzproq20/)

Comment: My problem is that I have to display either `cc.NAME_IT` or `cc.NAME_US`, not both at the same time... thanks anyway.

Comment: specify the condition in your question as well, on which you want to show the NAME or IT?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your controller:

```
.controller('YourController', ['countries', function(countries) {
    this.countries = countries;
}]
```

Now, you can use it as you did in the view.

NOTE: It is highly recommended to define constant in **uppercase**. ie. `COUNTRIES` in your case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cc in ctrl.countries" ng-bind-html="cc[language]"></li>
        <!-- language could be NAME_US or NAME_IT -->
    </ul>
```